# Annoying uv or pbr map After sending project

Tags: rendering, texturing

hey i'm having a problem with my pbr texture, i've baked it, everything looks fine, i'm working on the project in blender version 2.79

then I send the project to the client, when my client opens it, there is a strange texture, such as an irregular texture like the image I put in

[image]

[

1. [image]

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5q17.png)

My client opens the project in blender 2.83, I think it's just a different version of the blender, then I installed blender 2.83 and opened my project, everything looks fine but why when my client opens it the texture becomes weird, so also uses unity

[image]

This is link for the file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1taEKN33XByWa-eFgzsyOpS3JYOltuYe9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the Normal Map is set to *sRGB* (the values are then gamma corrected).
Make sure your client has it set to *Non-Color*.

It works just fine for me, Blender 2.83.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, sir, that was very helpful, I hope God will bless you

Comment: Hey, how about the unity, that problem is not solved in unity

Comment: Hello :). I don't use unity, so can't help with that.

Comment: Ok thank you, no problem you have help me, sorry my english so bad